# Can I bring a diamond engagement ring to Singapore from VietNam, which was bought in VietNam?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel

I'm going to bring an engagement diamond ring from Vietnam to Singapore in the December. I just want to make sure could I get it through customs gate ?.

I know there is a similar topic here [link](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103722/bringing-engagement-ring-to-singapore-which-was-bought-in-germany), however, it's from five years ago. It would be better to know the latest information

Comment: Nothing has changed. As long as you're no bringing rings in bulk and have a ticket to leave Singapore, you'll be fine.

Comment: Are you a Singapore citizen or resident, or are you (and the ring) just going to be there for a few days?

Comment: @jcaron I'm not a Singapore resident, this trip is just a short vacation of 4 days

Comment: @lambshaanxy Thank you

Comment: Why not just wear it and pass customs? Personal jewelry is anyway exempted.